# JBPM Rest payload with float value

Tags: api, rest, jbpm

I have a process that has a variable of Float data type, and i want to start it using REST Api

In the POST payload i am writing this:

```
{   
  "amount":500.0
}
```

But when the process tries to start the value amount is received as Double not Float; i understand that this is the default behavior in JBoss but i want to know how to send amount as Float

By the way, this does not work

```
{
"amount": 500.0f
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable strict mode with the system property

```
org.jbpm.variable.strict=true
```

and make sure you are using jbpm 7.52.0.Final or above.

This test is currently working:

```
float percentage = 99.9f;
processClient.setProcessVariable(CONTAINER_ID, processInstanceId, "percentage", percentage);
assertEquals( percentage, ((Number)processClient.getProcessInstanceVariable(CONTAINER_ID, processInstanceId, "percentage")).floatValue(), 0.001f);
```